# How to attach /register event mongo listener in loopback-connector-mongodb

Tags: loopback4

I want to know how to register for these events in loopback 4
i am using loopback-connector-mongodb

```
["timeout",
      "close",
      "serverOpening",
      "serverDescriptionChanged",
      "serverHeartbeatStarted",
      "serverHeartbeatSucceeded",
      "serverHeartbeatFailed",
      "serverClosed",
      "topologyOpening",
      "topologyClosed",
      "topologyDescriptionChanged",
      "joined",
      "left",
      "ping",
      "ha",
      "all",
      "fullsetup",]
```

i am registering the events like this

```
   client.on("connected", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received mongodb connected event ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("serverOpening", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverOpening": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("serverClosed", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverClosed": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("serverDescriptionChanged", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverDescriptionChanged": ${JSON.stringify(
          event,
          null,
          2,
        )}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("topologyOpening", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "topologyOpening": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });
    client.on("topologyClosed", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "topologyClosed": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("topologyDescriptionChanged", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "topologyDescriptionChanged": ${JSON.stringify(
          event,
          null,
          2,
        )}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("serverHeartbeatStarted", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverHeartbeatStarted": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });

    client.on("serverHeartbeatSucceeded", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverHeartbeatSucceeded": ${JSON.stringify(
          event,
          null,
          2,
        )}`,
      );
    });
    client.on("serverHeartbeatFailed", (event) => {
      customLogger.info(
        `received "serverHeartbeatFailed": ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`,
      );
    });
```

but when the connection is established only  "Connected" is being triggered and not others
I assume "serverOpening" and "topologyOpening" should also get called as per their description
[image]
[image]

can someone help me solve/understand this?

Comment: Where did you put the event listeners? What does the `client` variable contains? Is it the loopback datasource instance?

Comment: Yes it is a loopback datasource instance